# C# 4.0, Methods on the fly?

Tags: c#-4.0

With the introduction of things like duck typing, I would love it if I compose object methods on the fly, besides extension methods.  Anybody know if this is possible?  I know that MS is worried about composing framework on the fly, but they seem to be dipping their toes in the water.

Update: Thanks to Pavel for clarifying.  For example, say I return a new dynamic object from LINQ and would like to add some methods to it on the fly.

Comment: Do you mean runtieme code generation? Or do you mean adding methods to objects dynamically, a la JavaScript?

Comment: The later.  Looks like you can do it with expression trees, but what a PITA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In light of the updated answer, you're actually not looking for "dynamic methods", so much so as "dynamic objects" - such that you may add new properties and methods to them at runtime. If that is correct, then in .NET 4.0, you can use [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(VS.100).aspx) in conjunction with `dynamic`:

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
foo.Bar = 123; // creates a new property on the fly
int x = foo.Bar; // 123

// add a new method (well, a delegate property, but it's callable as method)
foo.Baz = (Func<int, int, int>)
    delegate(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    };

foo.Baz(1, 2); // 3
```

You can have "dynamic methods" too, with expression trees, and once you obtain a delegate for such a method, you can also create a callable method-like property out of it on an `ExpandoObject`.

For use in LINQ queries, unfortunately, you cannot use object initializers with `ExpandoObject`; in the simplest case, the following will not compile:

```
var foo =  new ExpandoObject { Bar = 123; }
```

The reason is that `Bar` in this case will be looked up statically as a property of `ExpandoObject`. You need the receiver to be `dynamic` for this feature to kick in, and there's no way to make it that inside an object initializer. As a workaround for use in LINQ, consider this helper extension method:

```
public static dynamic With(this ExpandoObject o, Action<dynamic> init)
{
     init(o);
     return o;
}
```

Now you can use it thus:

```
from x in xs
select new ExpandoObject().With(o => {
    o.Foo = x;
    o.Bar = (Func<int, int>)delegate(int y) { return x + y; };
});
```

Comment: Nice!  What if I created a dynamic object with LINQ (returning specified properties), is that an ExpandoObject that I can add methods to?

Comment: Anonymous types (created via `new { ... }` with no class specified after `new`) are not expando. For the rest of the story, check out the edited answer.

Comment: That's good work.  Just some syntax corrections to get this to compile.  Replace Action<> with Func<>, and need to put ';' after dynamic property/method creations instead of ','

Comment: @Trent, thanks, updated the code to fix mistakes that you've pointed out.

Comment: +1 clear and useful answer. Something to look forward to and experiment with on a rainy day :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is: [Generating Dynamic Methods with Expression Trees in Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2009/09/14/generating-dynamic-methods-with-expression-trees-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Comment: This only works for static methods. See this post: http://www.justnbusiness.com/post/2009/08/02/LambdaExpressionCompileToMethod-e280a6-not-nearly-as-cool-as-I-had-hoped.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This was already possible with the aid of `DynamicMethod` and/or `MethodBuilder`. Not sure if that counts for being "worried", as it has been around for a while now, though it requires a dynamic assembly in most scenarios (`DynamicMethod` can be used without, though).

Comment: When I say worried, I mean this http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/09/86979.aspx.  I was hoping to avoid reflection, but thanks for the tip

Comment: sorry, pun was a bit intended. As you've found out, no need to use reflection. Nice answer Pavel wrote down!